# Cloudflare is blocking me from my wordpress site for trying to add a javascript code snippet from a zoho chat plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cloudflare, zoho

I'm trying to add a chat widget to a WordPress site and have Cloudflare installed.
To add this chat widget I downloaded the Zoho SalesIQ plugin, and it says "Just paste the SalesIQ code snippet here." A javascript code. but when I try to do that I get blocked from the site by Cloudflare.

Is there a way to add this js code snippet to the chat plugin without being blocked?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00yKO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58D2j.png)

Comment: Please post some code or screenshots of what you did so far.

Comment: I just added the screen shots from the plugin where I tried to add the javascript code, and then the message saying I was blocked. I also tried this: https://www.namehero.com/startup/where-to-put-custom-code-in-wordpress-hint-use-a-plugin/ but I also got the the same message that I was blocked...